# actionbar in desired activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-manifest

I have a question about the styles.xml. 
When I set the windowActionBar to false, this will be set to all my activities in my application. I don't want that. I just want that for my first activity (splash screen), and my next activity WILL have an actionbar.

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

I thought that if I set a custom theme to my next activity this problem will be a thing of the past. Here's my manifest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme2"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But I have the same problem still... How can I make the actionbar visible for only the second activity?!

Answer (score 0):

Your splash activity should use no action bar theme like below:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
         ></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: The same thing occurs in the next activity, there are no actionbar visible there :/

Comment: What does your main activity extend from?

Comment: AppCompatActivity

Comment: Change application theme to your main activity theme

Answer (score 0):

```
You can have toolbar in any activity in which you want to have actionbar 

You can set title programmatically to a toolbar 
ActionBar ActionBar;
Toolbar toolbar = findviewid(R.id.toolbaar);
Setsupportactionbar(toolbaar);
actionbar= getsupportactionbar();
actionbar.settitle("your title");
```